# Type Error _interopRequireDefault is not a function while running test cases in jest or enzyme

Tags: typescript, react-native, compiler-errors, typeerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ylm.png)

While running yarn test command for run the test cases in your system that time we are getting this  error to solve this issue i have deep research about this problem. and tried every solution but nothings work for me.

Solution for that is add in our main package.json this dependency

"@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.69.0",

it will work for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.